# jQuery - can't get the 'this' to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

i've managed to get a simple animation working so when I roll over my div with the class "gallery-wrap", an image with the class "magnifier" appears on top.

My problem is I have lots of divs with the class "gallery-wrap" and lots of images which have the class "magnifier".

```
    $("img.magnifier").hide(); //this hides the image on page load

    $('.gallery-wrap').hover(function() {   
        $("img.magnifier").show();            
            }, function() {
        $("img.magnifier").hide();
    });
```

The `img.magnifier` is located inside the `.gallery-wrap` parent div, not inside `.gallery-wrap`.

I need it so this does only the current hovered element, which it is doing already, but its animating all the `img.magnifier` on the page?

I thought it would maybe look like this...

```
    $("img.magnifier").hide(); //this hides the image on page load

    $('.gallery-wrap').hover(function() {   
        $(this).parent("img.magnifier").show();            
            }, function() {
        $(this).parent("img.magnifier").hide();
    });
```

But cannot get it to work.

Any ideas would be a huge help thanks.

Comment: Post your actual html. parent("img.magnifier") only works if the parent of this is the exact img.magnifier.  Try .parents("img.magnifier")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with:

```
$(this).parent("img.magnifier").show();
```

Change it to:

```
$(this).parent().find("img.magnifier").show();
```

Then it should work. Do the same thing with your `hide()` of course.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
$('.gallery-wrap').hover(function() {   
    $(this).find("img.magnifier").show();            
        }, function() {
    $(this).find("img.magnifier").hide();
});
```

If I understand correctly, `img.magnifier` is a child of `.gallery-wrap`, so `find()` should be used instead of `parent()`.

Comment: Hello, sorry I badly explained the question. I meant the img.magnifier was located inside the parent div of .gallery-wrap - so this word for me.. $(this).parent().find("img.magnifier").show();

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign matching id values to the gallery-wrap and associated img.magnifier?

```
$('.gallery-wrap').hover(function() {   

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("img.magnifier#"+id).show();            
        }, function() {
    $("img.magnifier#"+id).hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change:

```
$(this).parent("img.magnifier")
```

to:

```
$(this).find("img.magnifier")
```

since the img tag is a child element of your gallery-wrap.

Comment: I assume that this was downvoted because I proposed using the find or children function when find is the appropriate choice for this scenario?

Comment: No the img is located in the gallery-wrap parent div.

Answer (score -1):

As img.magnifier is not inside .gallery-wrap, find() will not do it here.

Try this one:

```
    $("img.magnifier").hide(); //this hides the image on page load

    $('.gallery-wrap').hover(function() {   
        $(this).parents("img.magnifier").last().show();            
            }, function() {
        $(this).parents("img.magnifier").last().hide();
    });
```

The .last() is necessary if you have more than just one img.magnifier in the parents() collection.